# Turn an application or script into a shell command

Tags: python, shell, command-line

When I want to run my python applications from commandline (under ubuntu) I have to be in the directory where is the source code app.py and run the application with command

`python app.py`

How can I make it (how is it conventionally done) to run the application from arbitrary directory with the command: `app` ? Similarly as you type `ls`, `mkdir` and other commands?

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the directory that the script is in to your path, make it executable, and add a proper shebang line.

In your `.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/dir/to/the/script
```

Executable:

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

At the top of the script, add the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Then, from anywhere, you can just do:

```
myscript.py
```

(Note that you don't need a .py suffix, it could be called anything, e.g. `app` if you have a proper shebang line).

Answer (score 10):

1. Add a [shebang line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the beginning of your file:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   ```
2. Make your file executable by calling

   ```
   chmod +x app.py
   ```

   in the shell.
3. Move it to some location included in the `PATH` environment variable and rename it to `app`.  Alternatively, add the path of the directory containing `app` to the `PATH` environment variable by adding the line

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/app
   ```

   to your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: @xralf: I actually consider `.bashrc` the wrong place for this, since you will end up with multiple instance of the path in the `PATH` variable (which works, but seems pointless).  I don't know why `.bash_profile` does not work for you -- maybe it's called `.profile` on Ubuntu, or your login shell isn't `bash` (unlikely) or Ubuntu doesn't execute your login shell upon X login.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Add a shebang:** as the top line of the file: `#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` (you can use the `python -B` to prevent generation of `.pyc` files, which is why I don't use `/usr/bin/env`)
2. **Make it executable:** You will need to do `chmod +x app.py`
3. **(optional) Add directory to path, so can call it anywhere:** Add a directory with your executable to your `$PATH` environment variable. How you do so depends on your shell, but is either `export PATH=$PATH:/home/you/some/path/to/myscripts` (e.g. Linux distros which use bash) or `setenv PATH $PATH:/home/you/some/path/to/myscripts` (e.g. tcsh like in Mac OS X). You will want to put this, for example, in your `.bashrc` or whatever startup script you have, or else you will have to repeat this step every time you log in.

`app.py` will need to be in the `myscripts` (or whatever you name it) folder. You don't even need to call it `app.py`, but you can just rename it `app`.

If you wish to skip step #3, you can still do `./app` to run it if you are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to symlink to your file location instead of adding another location to the path

```
chmod +x app.py
ln ~app.py /opt/local/bin/app
```

...assuming that /opt/local/bin is already in your path,.

Also, do not forget to add the shebang line to the first line of your script:
`#!/usr/bin/env python`

Answer (score 1):

A solution some what different from the ones mentioned here: Use an alias.

```
alias app='python /path/to/app.py'
```

Add the above line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_login` file (or preferably to `~/.bash_aliases` if you are on Ubuntu). Then you can simply use your script as a command line tool with `app`.

No need to add a shebang (thereby modifying your existing Python script), no need to make the script executable and no need to change your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have to make the script executable via `chmod +x` and put it in the PATH variable of your system.