# Filter a command's output by occurrences of a certain character?

Tags: python, shell, unix, pipe, find-occurrences

So say I have a command, such as `ls`. And the output is large, and I want to filter it by the number of occurrences of the character ':'. The occurrences wouldn't need to be consecutive, they'd simply need to occur. Any line with ten or more of these occurrences should be sent to the output. Is there a way to do this? I was thinking of doing a python script, and making it a command, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163087/turn-an-application-or-script-into-a-shell-command), but I wasn't sure how I'd format the script, and what I could and couldn't do in terms of piping output from a previous command into this new script/command.

Comment: BTW, many experts advise against parsing the output of `ls`, but I guess it's not a big deal if you're only doing it on your own machine. See [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls), and [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

A shell solution would involve calling `awk`.

```
ls | awk -F: 'NF<9'
```

This reads the standard-out from `ls` sends it to a pipe, and `awk` splits each line into fields based on `:`. The `NF` mean Number of Fields. When `NF` is greater than `9`, the record will be printed.

you can extend this to filter on any number by passing in a variable

```
ls | awk -F: -v minCnt=10 'NF<=minCnt`
```

IHTH

Answer (score 1):

Using extended regular expressions:

```
ls | egrep '(:.*){10,}'
```

Example, from `man bash`, show all lines with *15* or more "*e*"s, then highlight them in color:

```
COLUMNS=80 man bash | egrep --color '(e.*){15,}' | grep --color e
```

Output, (the colored part is in boldface):

> gr**e**at**e**r than 9 ar**e** r**e**pr**e**s**e**nt**e**d by th**e** low**e**rcas**e** l**e**tt**e**rs, th**e**  upp**e**rcas**e**

Answer (score 0):

You can read from standard input, filter and write to standard output:

```
# script.py
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.count(':') >= 10:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Call:

```
> ls | python script.py
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and filter airodump-ng?